# Angular.js uibModal data not passing to component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am making app in angular.js and when i am using uibModal and i want to pass data to modal, then its not working. 
I added console.log to callback function and it shows data in console

My open modal code is :

```
$scope.openEditModal = function (application) {
  $uibModal.open({
    animation: true,
    templateUrl: 'editDocument.html',
    controller: 'EditModalController',
    size: 'lg',
    backdrop: 'static',
    resolve: {
      activeApplication: function () {
        console.log(application);
        return application;
      }
    }
  });
};
```

And i am trying to display it this way :

```
<div>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="editDocument.html">
    <div class="modal-body">
      {{ activeApplication }}
    </div>
  </script>
</div>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you assign activeApplication to scope inside EditModalController?

Comment: Please show your `EditModalController`